# How to use Microsoft.Extesions.ILogger together with NLog?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog, ilogger

I have a system and I want to make a custom logs to create separate folders for each user. Now, I made it in NLog.Logger like a custom file target

```
public static LogFactory ConfigureCustomNLog(string userName)
        {
            var target = new FileTarget();
            target.Name = "fileLog";
            target.FileName = $"${{basedir}}/log" + $"/{userName}/{userName}" + "${shortdate}.log";
            target.Layout =
                "${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}} ${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace}";

            var config = ConfigureNLog("NLog.Config").Configuration;
            config.RemoveTarget("fileLog");
            config.AddTarget(target.Name, target);

            var rule = new LoggingRule(userName, LogLevel.Debug, target);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

            LogManager.Configuration = config;

            return LogManager.LogFactory;
        }
```

Everything is working fine, but I want to use like Microsoft.Extensions.ILogger. How I can import NLog.Logger to ILogger? Or how I can make custom config for ILogger?

Comment: Nlog has a special nuget package with methods to incorporate nlog loggers into the MS ILogger. I don't remember what it's called but I know it exists as I used it before switching to Serilog, which also has a similar package. Just check their github page there's surely instructions

Comment: For console apps https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application they also have wiki pages for aspnet. Yes the console app page talks about netcore2 but it's just as applicable to later versions (just use newer packages). The aspnet instructions are a bit better honestly and you can follow them mostly for console apps too (just don't use the nlog.aspnetcore package)

Answer (score 10):

Normally Microsoft ILogger is used together with dependency injection. Like described here:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application

But you can also do it manually:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger Logger;
 
    public MyClass(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType().ToString());
        Logger.LogInformation("Hello");
    }
}

var loggerFactory = new NLog.Extensions.Logging.NLogLoggerFactory();
var myClass = new MyClass(loggerFactory);
```

If you are building a Web-Application then this might help: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-5